# In Flutter App Icons are not showing in android devices

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbt2I.png)

I attached the image for your verification and can you please answer any one to my question to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe trying changing the color?

Comment: Please add some code for the same

Comment: I given black color only for icons, but it is not coming @MiguelRuivo

Comment: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              size: 25,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),

This is one of the example for this problem

Comment: IconTheme you need to set the icon.

Comment: Please, show the code for that drawer.

Answer (score 0):

i've same error. i run "flutter clean" in terminal and i run "flutter run" again. this is maybe can help you, because this work for my error. good luck

Answer (score 0):

`Icon( Icons.people, size: 28),` // default color is white so it seems like invisible

`Icon( Icons.people, size: 28, color: Colors.red),`  // now you can see the icon